# QTP code to update test status in QC

Tags: qtp

I am working on QTP 10.0 and I am looking to update my testcases in QC from QTP.
Can someone please pass me the code. The code which I got from the internet is using TDAPIOle80 object which I think is used for Test Director. Presently for QC we should be using QCUtil. Can someone please help me on this

Answer (score 2):

Try this link. Here it gives step by step in different blog entries, on how to make Quality center connection, how to open a qtp test , how to save test execution results etc all through vbscript file.

[VBscript sample example for QTP and QC](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/vbs-scripts-as-best-tools.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you hints how to find your way in the QC API, but connecting to QC and finding a testcase is a higher science while updating the testcase with correct runsteps is even more challenging. You certainly need the QC API documentation to really unlock all possibilities: Login to QC, go to Help-->Documentation library and download it there.

I used to use `Set tdc = QCUtil.QCConnection` for setting the QCConnection, but it turned out to be unstable in our projects.
Now using `Set tdc = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")` and that is working. As an extra benefit, I you generalize your code enough you can use library where you use the TDApiOle80 method outside QTP (in plains VBS or VBA).

After making the tdc object, you can use
`tdc.InitConnectionEx "https://qualitycenter.mydomain.com:8443/qcbin"` to connect
and
`tdc.Login "User01", "Password01"` to login.

If you have a authorized connection you can iterate through your releasenodes with
`Set ReleaseNodes = tdc.TestSetTreeManager.Root.Subnodes` < returns a releasenodes collection. When there are subnodes, you can recursively iterate the subnodes until you have found the releasenode you are aiming for.

Once you have a valid releasenode, you need the testinstance (testcase). You can find a testcase by using: `FindTestInstances("MyTestcase", False, "")` (this returns a collection of matching testcases)

You can update the status of a testcase by creating a RunStep with the RunFactory and add it to the testcase.